# Enable TLSV1.1 &TLS1.2 in Mule ESB

Tags: ssl, mule

To enable SSL/TLS protocols I had updated tls-default.conf file with "enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"entry. And also add wrapper.java.additional.=-Djavax.net.debug=ssl to enable SSL debugging.

After running Mule I got the logs mentioned below:

**ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:...
..
ServerHello, TLSv1**

From the above logs it is clear that TLSv1 is used instead of TLSv1.2

I am using Mule Version 3.5.2
And JDK 7 which has SunJSSE security provider which allows (PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1) protocols.

Is there any way to find out the enabled protocols apart from looking into SSL Handshake logs?

Comment: If this is related to running mule with FIPS, then you might want to try adding that line to tls-fips140-2.conf.

Comment: Same problem is happening while running Mule in FIPS mode after updating tls-fips140-2.conf.

Comment: And this is happening for which transport? HTTPS?

Comment: Yes It is happening for HTTPS transport. I also want to know how Mule enables the protocols for SSL is it refer both conf file and JDK  security provider or is it only refer conf file. If it refers both JDK & conf then how it decides which protocol to enable ?

Comment: Both conf file and JDK security provider are considered. I'd recommend taking a look at these classes to get a better idea of what might be going on: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/api/security/tls/RestrictedSSLServerSocketFactory.java and https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/api/security/tls/RestrictedSSLSocketFactory.java

Comment: Does your provider allow TLSv1.2? Cause you only mention SSLv3 and TLSv1. That might be why TLSv1 is use.

Comment: SunJSSE supports all four SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2 but by default only two SSLv3 & TLSv1 are enabled. TLSv1.1 & TLSv1.2 need to be explicitly enabled to use. Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html for reference.

Comment: Does this happen for the outbound or inbound HTTPS? I think this issue might not have been entirely fixed on one side: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7663